# Integral of Euler class of tangent bundle and the generalized Gauss-Bonnet Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

**Definition of Euler Class that I've been given** 
Let $\Sigma$ be a compact orientable manifold of dimension 2 with metric $g$ on the tangent bundle $T\Sigma$, and connection $\nabla$ and curvature $F_{\nabla}$. For sections $s_1$, $s_2$ of $T\Sigma$, we can define the map
$$
\omega(s_1,s_2) = g(F_{\nabla}s_1,s_2)
$$
It can be seen that $\omega\in \Omega^{2}(\Sigma; \Lambda^{2}T^{*}\Sigma)$ and that $\nabla\omega = 0$.

For any two local frames $\{s_1,s_2\}$ and $\{s'_1,s'_2\}$ of $T\Sigma$ with the same orientation, we find that $s_1\wedge s_2 = s'_1\wedge s'_2$, and hence $\Lambda^{2}T\Sigma$ admits a nowhere vanishing section, say $\sigma\in \Omega^{2}(\Sigma; \Lambda^{2}T\Sigma)$.

If we take $e$ to be the natural pairing $\langle\omega,\sigma\rangle$, then the **Euler class** of $T\Sigma$, $\varepsilon(T\Sigma)$, may be defined as the cohomology class of $e$, i.e. $\varepsilon(T\Sigma) = [e]\in H^{2}(\Sigma)$. It can be shown that this is independent of the choice of metric and connection.

**Definition of Riemann Curvature**
For vector fields $X,Y,Z,W$, we may define
$$
R(X,Y,Z,W) = g(F_{\nabla}(X,Y)Z,W)
$$
This satisfies the expected symmetry and anti-symmetry properties, as in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannTensor.html.

In particular, for the manifold $\Sigma$, we can relate the Riemann curvature to the Gauss curvature $K$ and a non-vanishing section $\sigma \in \Omega^{2}(\Sigma; \Lambda^{2}T\Sigma)$ by the following formula (for $x\in \Sigma$)
$$
R(X,Y,Z,W)\mid_{x} = K(x)\sigma(X,Y)\sigma(Z,W)
$$
**What I've been asked to show**
$$
\int_{\Sigma}\varepsilon(T\Sigma) = \int_{\Sigma}K\sigma
$$
**What I'm trying to understand**

1. This formula looks very like the Gauss-Bonnet formula for surfaces to me, especially if I consider the case where $\sigma = dS$, some surface element. In this case, I would expect that the left-hand-side of the equation should equal $2\pi\chi(\Sigma)$. Unfortunately, I don't fully understand how to reconcile my definition of the Euler class with a formula for the Euler characteristic. Different (presumably compatible) definitions have been mentioned in other questions on this site (e.g. the answer given by Elden Elmanto in [Euler class of tangent bundle of the sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469134/euler-class-of-tangent-bundle-of-the-sphere), and also here: [How to interpret the Euler class?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105966/how-to-interpret-the-euler-class)), but I can't figure out how they tie back to this integral formula.
2. Would it be wiser to try to solve the problem using the pairing $\langle \omega, \sigma\rangle$, rather than going through the Gauss-Bonnet theorem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should be a simple calculation, which looks to me more like part of a proof of Gauss-Bonnet than something that should be invoking it. I think you will in fact have the pointwise equality $e=K\sigma.$

Comment: Your formula $R(X,Y,Z,W)=K(x) \sigma (X,Y) \sigma (Z,W)$ is not correct as the rhs depends on the   choice of $\sigma$, whereas the lhs is well defined. I think you must choose $\sigma $ to be the riemannian volume form, then $e=K\sigma$.

Comment: AnthonyCarapetis and Thomas, thank you both for sharing your insights. I will try to use the Riemannian volume form to obtain the pointwise equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in the conclusion to this question, Anthony Carapetis provided an excellent answer in the linked question [Interchanging Duals and Metrics for Riemann Curvature Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2639174/interchanging-duals-and-metrics-for-riemann-curvature-definition).